# Permutations of a four character string made up of only numbers 0-9

Tags: c++, c++11

Hello thanks for reading my question. I was hoping to figure out how to store all the possible permutations of a 4 character string made up of only numbers, there can be repetition.

```
char str[] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};

sort(begin(str), end(str));
do{
    cout << str[0] << ' ' << str[1] << ' ' << str[2] << ' ' << str[3] << '\n';
}while(next_permutation(begin(str), end(str)));
```

The code above is what I have right now. It prints the permutations but I am not sure how to store them. Also it loops past the permutations I need after 9999 it seems to start over. I am looking for a way to store '0000', '0001', '0002', '0003', '0004',......,'9999' (0000-9999) into a vector of strings. I must do this without recursion and use of the STL is accepted.

Comment: If repetition is allowed, this is usually called `cartesian product`, not `permutations`.

Comment: Code shown cannot produce '0000' etc, please edit your question to contain [mcve]

Comment: See cartesian_product.

Comment: @user10605163 [Combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) isn't the right word either - it implies order doesn't matter.

Comment: @TypeIA Thanks, don't know why I said `combinations`.

Comment: `char buf[5]; for(int i{}; i < 10000; ++i) { std::sprintf(buf, "%04d", i); result.push_back(buf); }` \m/ ^_^ \m/

Comment: @bipll Yeah, I'm pretty sure that's not what the OP are supposed to do... ;)

Answer (score 3):

Just store the numbers 0 through 9999 in the vector of strings. There is no need to use next_permutation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  vector<string> nums;

  for(int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
    string num = to_string(i);
    nums.push_back(string(4 - num.length(), '0') + num);
  }

  for(string& s: nums) {
    cout << s << " ";
  }
  cout << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: for(it = nums.begin(); it!=nums.end(); it++){
        cout << *it << "\n";
    } when I try to iterate over the vector using this it results in a infinite loop

Comment: Use the new for loop syntax: ```for(string& str: nums) { cout << str << endl; }```

Comment: The new syntax gives me the same result.

Comment: Are you sure you copied it right? I modified my answer to form a complete example that works for me.

Comment: sorry that was my mistake, the function I put it in loops and that totally went past my head lol

Answer (score 1):

I tried to wrote this code fast, that's why I used the MACRO `DIGITFOR`.

```
#define DIGITFOR(i) for (char i='0'; i <= '9'; i++)
vector<string> permutations;

DIGITFOR(i) DIGITFOR(j) DIGITFOR(k) DIGITFOR(l){
    char cad[5];
    cad[4]='\0';
    cad[0]=i;
    cad[1]=j;
    cad[2]=k;
    cad[3]=l;
    permutations.push_back(cad);
}
```

Comment: Do you mind writing the "human readable and compilable" version of this code too? Something like this: https://wandbox.org/permlink/6NfDavUtcbMP4tO3

Comment: @Bob__ That's a really better example.